# How do I write specific conditions for the first order of the day?

Tags: pine-script

I want to write a different entry condition for the first order of the day and different entry condition for the rest of the orders in the day. I want to write the following for Long Entry.

```
Long_Entry = Is_First_Order ? First_Order_condition : Other_Order_condition
```

But I am not sure how to write the `Is_First_Order` condition. Note that the first order need not be at the open of the day, could be after a few candles as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `change()` function to check for changes in a variable. In this case you would apply it to a builtin time variable such as `dayofmonth`. This with a persistent variable to track, which is reset on the first bar of a given day. Then when executing the first order, set the variable to false.

```
//@version=4
study("conditions test", overlay=true)

var bool firstOrder = true
if change(dayofmonth)
    firstOrder := true

entryCondition = true

if entryCondition and firstOrder
    firstOrder := false

plot(close)
```